# compare vector to dataframe by applying identical with booleans

Tags: r

Apply does not work, but using identical directly does:
Create the dataframe

```
gp130 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=7,ncol=6))
rownames(gp130) <- c("ABCDEF","ABCDE","ABCD","ABC","AB","BCDEF","MUCV5")
names(gp130) <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
gp130$A <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
gp130$B <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
gp130$C <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
gp130$D <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
gp130$E <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
gp130$F <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Evaluate dataframe

```
  gp130
           A     B     C     D     E     F
ABCDEF  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
ABCDE   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
ABCD    TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
ABC     TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
AB      TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
BCDEF  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
MUCV5  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Create a vector that matches column C

```
myv <- c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE) ##matches column C


apply(gp130,  2, identical, myv)
   A     B     C     D     E     F 
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Why is C FALSE?

```
identical(gp130$C, myv)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I'm puzzled, specially because it works if you substitute `sapply` for `apply`: `sapply(gp130, identical, myv)`.

Comment: `apply` coerces your dataframe to a matrix. If you do `apply(gp130,  2, function(x) identical(as.vector(x),myv))`, C returns TRUE. Also, if you do `identical(as.matrix(gp130)[,3],myv)`, it returns FALSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I've got it. `sapply`strips the column names, while `apply` doesn't, the vectors become named vectors. See the output of the two versions below.

```
apply(gp130,  2, function(x){
    identical(x, myv)
    print(x)  # prints names
    print(myv)
})
sapply(gp130, function(x){
    identical(x, myv)
    print(x)
    print(myv)
})
```

Comment: Correct. An important thing to note is that `identical(x,y)` is a **lot** more strict than `all(x==y)`. One example is what you see here, columnnames and such have to be the same as well for `identical` to return `TRUE`. This also applies to classes and attributes of compared objects. See `?identical`.